# How to get the total number of Facebook Page Likes

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook Graph API v3. If you guys know the simplest way to get the total number of page likes much appreciated.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Using a Page access token for the Page in question, issue a GET request to `me/insights?metric=page_fans`.

The resulting output will be along these lines:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "page_fans",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": 36,
          "end_time": "2018-05-04T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": 36,
          "end_time": "2018-05-05T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ],
      "title": "Lifetime Total Likes",
      "description": "Lifetime: The total number of people who have liked your Page. (Unique Users)",
      "id": ".../insights/page_fans/lifetime"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "previous": "...",
    "next": "..."
  }
}
```

If the Page is not under your control (and thus, you can't get a Page token), you can issue a GET request to the Page with a `fields=fan_count`, i.e.  `/Google?fields=fan_count`. The resulting output will be like this:

```
{
  "fan_count": 26034652,
  "id": "104958162837"
}
```

Comment: the thing is the access token I got is valid for only 1 hour, Im planning to display the total number of page likes on a website

Comment: @CarloSaquilayan Then [extend the token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) or use an application-level token and the second approach.